# Creating a SoftKeyboard with Multiple/Alternate characters per key

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I've followed the examples on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/) regarding  [Input Methods](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html) and played with the [SoftKeyboard](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html) sample application. These together give more than enough information regarding the creation of simple keyboard.

What I can't see in the API is the ability to create alternate / multiple characters per key which is available on the standard Keyboard (LatinIME Keyboard).

[image]

The above image is the result of a long press on the "a" key. When you long press a key it's possible to populate a popup with alternate characters.

[image]

It is also possible to give a popup hint on some keys which will prompt the user to press and hold a key in order to get the popup menu.

So far I haven't found a single source of information on how this is achieved, hopefully someone will be able to give me a head start, until then I'll follow the source code of the inbuilt keyboard and see if I can reverse engineer it.

**Edit:** Would help if [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/) 's link to the LatinIME Keyboard didn't link to a picture of a [Sheep](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME.git;a=tree) :) Actual source code for [LatinIME.java](http://www.google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/java/src/com/android/inputmethod/latin/LatinIME.java&type=cs).

**Edit 2:** More as a reference than anything else, this is the sequence I believe a usual longPress action goes through in order to show the popup keyboard in [KeyboardView.java](http://www.google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java):

```
onTouchEvent()
onModifiedTouchEvent()
mHandkler.handleMessage() with MSG_LONGPRESS
openPopupIfRequired() 
onLongPress()
```

**Edit 3:**

I still haven't figured this out - How do you add label suggestions to keys? An answer suggests it isn't built into the API and indeed I haven't found the codeto do this. However the Keyboard on 2.3.4 (API 10) shows this functionality being implemented:

[image]

Would very much like to figure out how IT does it but it isn't anywhere in the `onDraw()` method that I can see - which makes me believe it's being written outside of the KeyboardView element. I can't however find the `layout` file used to display the KeyboardView element on the inbuilt keyboard - If anyone knows where to find this perhaps that will give me the clue I need.

**Edit 4:** Moved key Preview question here as it's slightly off topic:

[How do you disable the SoftKeyboard key preview window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7770099/726954)

Comment: Did you find to solution to implement custom popups? please update

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**Implementing alternate key popup:**

For each key you wish to have a popup keyboard you should define [popupCharacters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html#attr_android:popupCharacters) and [popupKeyboard](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html#attr_android:popupKeyboard):

`/res/xml/[Keyboard].xml`

```
<Key android:keyLabel="("
    android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keyboard_popup_template"
    android:popupCharacters="[{&lt;" />
```

The `popupKeyboard` is an XML representation of the keyboard used in the popup containing the alternate keys:

`/res/xml/keyboard_popup_template.xml`

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="56dp">
</Keyboard>
```

**Styling the alternate key popup:**

If you want to change the layout/style of the popup (which defaults to [@android:layout/ keyboard_popup_keyboard.xml](http://www.google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/keyboard_popup_keyboard.xml)) you can specify a `android:popupLayout` attribute which points to a layout file:

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#FF272727"
    android:popupLayout="@layout/keyboard_popup_keyboard" />
```

**Implementing Key Preview Overlay:**

The only solution I've been able to knock together to show key previews (Without entirely rewriting the KeyboardView source code) is below:

Wrapping the `<KeyboardView>` tag with a `<FrameLayout>` with a height specified by multiplying the keyHeight by the amount of rows. Inside this tag I've simply created a LinearLayout to hold rows, then a LinearLayout for each row containing a TextView with a weight equal to the %p value specified for each `<Key>`:

```
<TextView android:text="!" style="@style/Custom.Widget.KeyboardKeyOverlay"  android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="10"/>
```

And styled:

```
<style name="CustomTheme.Widget.KeyboardKeyOverlay">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFAAAAAA</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Which produces this:

[image]

I won't be happy until I've managed to implement this in the same way as the System Keyboard does!

Comment: @Graeme,
I didn't understood implementing key preview overlay.
Do I include keyboardView within Framelayout? If Yes then How would keyboard rows have to be declared?
Please can you guide me show that I can develop descent IME.
Thanks.

Comment: @Graeme, can you provide the sources to your solution? Nice workaround, btw!

Comment: Is there a way to replace the default close button on the popup keyboard? I know you can change the layout but I'm trying to create a way for the user to close the popup keyboard by touching somewhere outside of its area.

Comment: may you add complete solution please, I missed up with overriding the custom keyboard for the multiple keys key.

Comment: Great answer. Sadly this link is dead: @android:layout/keyboard_popup_keyboard.xml) You are showing how to call for a custom popup-layout; could you please add an example of a custom styling file. I need nothing fancy, am just trying to give my popups the same background colour and frame-colour as my main (custom) keyboard. Thank you.

Comment: The working link for @android:layout/keyboard_popup_keyboard.xml: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/keyboard_popup_keyboard.xml

Answer (score 15):

Judging from my own attempt at coding a softkeyboard I found out that:

- Nice/bling features usually requires that you extend `KeyboardView` and basically write large parts of the drawing code. Unfortunately you *cannot* do this by overriding some key methods since almost everything is private. You might want to take a look (and borrow some code from:

  - `(base)/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java` (android core code repo)
  - `(apps)/other/LatinIME/LatinKeyboardView.java` (android core apps repo)

Note that the sheep on android.kernel.org is there to tell you that the repo is closed due to crackers but there are mirrors of the code elsewhere (lost the links unfortunately)

- The base [`KeyboardView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html) has *no* support for shadowed key hints, you must code your own KeyboardView to get a chance to override the onDraw() method.

Now on what you *can* do:

- You can workaround this issue by providing pictures for the keys: use xml `<Key ... android:keyIcon="@drawable/this_key_icon_file />` for this. Unfortunately, you'll most certainly have poor results for letters with this method (resolution issues).
- You can use (and configure appearance of) popup keyboard that appears on long press.

Declare a keyboard template `res/xml/kbd_popup_template.xml` :

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px"
    android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height">
</Keyboard>
```

Declare string values containing the keys you want on this keyboard `res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <string name="alternates_for_a">àáâãäåæ</string>
</ressources>
```

Then, use both in your keyboard layout definition:

```
<Key android:codes="97" android:keyLabel="a"  
    android:popupKeyboard="@xml/kbd_popup_template"
    android:popupCharacters="@string/alternates_for_a" />
```

- You can also use double-tap, triple-tap, ... feature to generate alternates for the key you're tapping. To do so, simply use a *list* for the android keycodes:

  `<Key android:codes="97,224,230" .../>`

will produce 97='`a`' for single tap, 224='`à`' for double-tap and 230='`æ`' for triple-tap.

The duration to consider double-tapping is set to 800ms in android source code. It's unfortunately hardcoded (and a bit high, I feel).

Be aware that, when double-tapping, it basically sends an '`a`' first, then, on the second tap it sends '`à`'. Some apps, will not like this.

Comment: Unfortunately when I follow this solution, there is an 'x' (close button) that appears with the popup characters.  And it won't go away until I select it or a character.  How can I avoid getting this 'x' button??

Comment: Hi Igor G., unfortunately I can not help you there: this doesn't happen to me neither on Froyo nor ICS. Maybe is this device/vendor dependant?

Comment: Thank you.  But I have tried with different devices, and different OS versions.  So maybe it's just my code.

Answer (score 12):

That popup keyboard with the close button is annoying when we have only one popup character.
Simpler way is to override the onLongPress method of KeyboardView class like this.

```
@Override
protected boolean onLongPress(Key key) {
    if (key.codes[0] == '1') {
        getOnKeyboardActionListener().onKey('!', null);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to have a text on top of your key, you can do it in onDraw() method in your class that overrides KeyboardView

```
 @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    ...
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    paint.setTextSize(18);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    //get all your keys and draw whatever you want
    List <Keyboard.Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
    for(Keyboard.Key key: keys) {
        if(key.label != null) {

            if (key.label.toString().equals("q") || key.label.toString().equals("Q"))
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(1), key.x + (key.width / 2) + 10, key.y + 25, paint);

            else if (key.label.toString().equals("w") || key.label.toString().equals("W"))
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(2), key.x + (key.width / 2) + 10, key.y + 25, paint);

            else if (key.label.toString().equals("e") || key.label.toString().equals("E"))
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(3), key.x + (key.width / 2) + 10, key.y + 25, paint);

            else if (key.label.toString().equals("r") || key.label.toString().equals("R"))
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(4), key.x + (key.width / 2) + 10, key.y + 25, paint);

            else if (key.label.toString().equals("t") || key.label.toString().equals("T"))
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(5), key.x + (key.width / 2) + 10, key.y + 25, paint);

            else if (key.label.toString().equals("y") || key.label.toString().equals("Y"))
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(6), key.x + (key.width / 2) + 10, key.y + 25, paint);

            else if (key.label.toString().equals("u") || key.label.toString().equals("U"))
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(7), key.x + (key.width / 2) + 10, key.y + 25, paint);

            else if (key.label.toString().equals("i") || key.label.toString().equals("I"))
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(8), key.x + (key.width / 2) + 10, key.y + 25, paint);

            else if (key.label.toString().equals("o") || key.label.toString().equals("o"))
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(9), key.x + (key.width / 2) + 10, key.y + 25, paint);

            else if (key.label.toString().equals("p") || key.label.toString().equals("P"))
                canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(0), key.x + (key.width / 2) + 10, key.y + 25, paint);

            else
            {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just an improvement suggestion over multiple if-else: use  `switch(key.codes[0]) { ... }` statement to speed up the code.

Comment: Yeah there are multiple ways to improve this code, for instance use equalsIgnoreCase() etc, the point is to show that you can draw that text programmatically. Anyway thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: isn't is expensive on lower devices because onDraw call twice when press any key from keyboard and release it?

Answer (score 6):

For anyone trying to dismiss the popup keyboard by tapping outside its view area, I've had some luck putting a `TouchListener` on the `KeyboardView` inside the class extending `InputMethodService`

```
public class YourIME extends InputMethodService{
    @Override 
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        mInputView = (LatinKeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.input, null);
        setLatinKeyboard(mQwertyKeyboard);

        mInputView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {                        
                    mInputView.closing(); // Close popup keyboard if it's showing
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        return mInputView;
    }
// The rest of your ime ...
}
```

Comment: There is just a problem here, if you click outside of the popup on the keyboard it will output the letter you clicked, need to add a condition to if so it only happens when the popup is open

Comment: In addition to this answer the undocumented method KeyboardView.handleBack() dismisses the popup keyboard http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java#1423
This can be called from onTouchEvent() in a class extended from KeyboardView when ACTION_UP occurs

Comment: I have this issue but this doesn't seem to do anything. Do setOnTouchListener and setOnKeyboardActionListener somehow collide, or...?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to have a text on top of your key, you can do it in onDraw() method in your class that extends KeyboardView i did something like this maybe this could help someone

[image]

```
 @Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Log.d("LatinKeyboardView", "onDraw");

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    paint.setTextSize(30);
    paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);

    List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
    for (Key key : keys) {
        if (key.label != null) {
            switch (key.codes[0]) {

                //qQ
                case 81:
                case 113:
                case 1602:
                case 1618:
                    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(1), key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;
                //wW
                case 87:
                case 119:
                case 1608:
                case 1572:
                    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(2), key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;

                //eE
                case 69:
                case 101:
                case 1593:
                case 1617:
                    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(3), key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;


                //rR
                case 82:
                case 114:
                case 1585:
                case 1681:
                    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(4), key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;
                //tT
                case 84:
                case 116:
                case 1578:
                case 1657:
                    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(5), key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;
                //yY
                case 89:
                case 121:
                case 1746:
                case 1552:
                    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(6), key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;
                //uU
                case 85:
                case 117:
                case 1569:
                case 1574:
                    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(7), key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;
                //iI
                case 73:
                case 105:
                case 1740:
                case 1648:
                    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(8), key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;
                //oO
                case 79:
                case 111:
                case 1729:
                case 1731:
                    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(9), key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;

                //pP
                case 80:
                case 112:
                case 1662:
                case 1615:
                    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(0), key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;


                //aA
                case 65:
                case 97:
                case 1575:
                case 1570:
                    canvas.drawText("@", key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;

                //sS
                case 83:
                case 115:
                case 1587:
                case 1589:
                    canvas.drawText("#", key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;
                //dD
                case 68:
                case 100:
                case 1583:
                case 1672:
                    canvas.drawText("$", key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;

                //fF
                case 70:
                case 102:
                case 1601:
                case 1613:
                    canvas.drawText("%", key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;

                //gG
                case 71:
                case 103:
                case 1711:
                case 1594:
                    canvas.drawText("&", key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;
                //hH
                case 72:
                case 104:
                case 1726:
                case 1581:
                    canvas.drawText("-", key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;
                //jJ
                case 74:
                case 106:
                case 1580:
                case 1590:
                    canvas.drawText("+", key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;

                //kK
                case 75:
                case 107:
                case 1705:
                case 1582:
                    canvas.drawText("(", key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;

                //lL
                case 76:
                case 108:
                case 1604:
                case 1614:
                    canvas.drawText(")", key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;
                //zZ
                case 90:
                case 122:
                case 1586:
                case 1584:
                    canvas.drawText("*", key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;

                //xX
                case 88:
                case 120:
                case 1588:
                case 1679:
                    canvas.drawText("\"", key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;

                //cC
                case 67:
                case 99:
                case 1670:
                case 1579:
                    canvas.drawText("\'", key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;

                //vV
                case 86:
                case 118:
                case 1591:
                case 1592:
                    canvas.drawText(":", key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;

                //bB
                case 66:
                case 98:
                case 1576:
                case 1616:
                    canvas.drawText(";", key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;

                //nN
                case 78:
                case 110:
                case 1606:
                case 1722:
                    canvas.drawText("!", key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;
                //mM
                case 77:
                case 109:
                case 1605:
                case 1611:
                    canvas.drawText("?", key.x + (key.width - keyXAxis), key.y + keyYAxis, paint);
                    break;


            }

        }

    }
}
```

adjust these axis according to your choice

```
int keyXAxis = 25;
int keyYAxis = 50;
```

Answer (score 2):

Base on the answers here, what I did was:

```
public class MyKeyboardView extends KeyboardView {
    private Keyboard.Key longPressedKey = null;

    public MyKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint.setTextSize(35);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        //get all your keys and draw whatever you want
        List<Keyboard.Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
        for (Keyboard.Key key : keys) {
            if (key.popupCharacters != null && key.popupCharacters.length() > 0) {
                canvas.drawText(key.popupCharacters.toString(), key.x + (key.width / 2) + 10, key.y + 30, paint);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected boolean onLongPress(Keyboard.Key key) {
        if (key.popupCharacters != null && key.popupCharacters.length() > 0)
            longPressedKey = key;
        return super.onLongPress(key);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (longPressedKey != null) {
                // TODO: Try detecting what key the finger is above if there are many popupCharacters
                getOnKeyboardActionListener().onKey((longPressedKey.popupCharacters.charAt(0)), null);
                dismissPopupKeyboard();
                longPressedKey = null;
            }
        }
        return true; // Required for recieving subsequent events (ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP)
    }

    private void dismissPopupKeyboard() {
        // Because of KeyboardView.dismissPopupKeyboard() is private, we are doing this trick (KeyboardView.click() calls dismissPopupKeyboard()).
        // TODO: Make this like a normal human. We will need to create the popup on our own like the way the keyboard does it.
        onClick(new View(getContext()));
    }
```

and

When used KeyboardView changed it to MyKeyboardView, with this extra param - `android:popupLayout="@layout/keyboard_popup_keyboard"`

And this is keyboard_popup_keyboard.xml (important so there wont be a cancel button)

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@android:id/keyboardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/popup_key_color"
        android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/key_preview"
        android:keyPreviewOffset="0px"
        android:keyPreviewHeight="@dimen/key_preview_height"
        android:keyTextColor="@color/darkGray"
        android:keyBackground="@drawable/key_background_selector"
        android:shadowRadius="0.0"
        android:horizontalGap="0px"
        android:verticalGap="0px" />
</LinearLayout>
```