# How do you disable the SoftKeyboard key preview window?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

When creating your own SoftKeyboard you are given a "key preview" by default.

[image] 
[image]

How do you disable this?

**Edit:**

You can customise the `keyPreview` layout by changing the `<KeyboardView>` attribute `android:keyPreviewLayout`. This is styled by default to look at [keyboard_key_preview.xml](http://www.google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/keyboard_key_preview.xml&type=cs):

**Edit 2:** *Following my be a red herring:*

The source code suggests supplying 0 or not applying the tag `android:keyPreviewLayout` will result in no key preview appearing:

```
    ...
    case com.android.internal.R.styleable.KeyboardView_keyPreviewLayout:
        previewLayout = a.getResourceId(attr, 0);
        break; 
    ...
    if (previewLayout != 0) {
        mPreviewText = (TextView) inflate.inflate(previewLayout, null);
        mPreviewTextSizeLarge = (int) mPreviewText.getTextSize();
        mPreviewPopup.setContentView(mPreviewText);
        mPreviewPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    } else {
        mShowPreview = false;
    }
```

I've tried:

- A styled KeyboardView with no keyPreviewLayout (Strangely though replacing this value changed the style of the preview.)
- I made a `keyPreviewLayout` reference an id with a value of 0 (which causes a crash on inflation).

Stumped. :( Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a method:

```
public void setPreviewEnabled(boolean previewEnabled)
```

But I don't know which version of the API that starts at.

Comment: This is implemented on the KeyboardView Object.  See the javadoc  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice

Answer (score 1):

Another way - add to xml 
**android:keyPreviewLayout="@null"**

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:keyPreviewLayout="@null"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
public static mEmptyView;

//somewhere where you have the context:
mEmptyView = new View(context);

@Override public View onCreateCandidatesView() {
    return mEmptyView;
}
```

This basically will always return an empty view, when the candidates should show up.

Comment: This stops the entire soft keyboard appearing. I have been returning `null` as standard: [InputMethodService.onCreateCandidatesView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onCreateCandidatesView())

Comment: Also, it's generally recommended you never keep View's as static members of a class as a view will keep a reference to his ancestors and can quite quickly build up memory leaks.

Comment: Yep it is better to create one in the method... I thought of that too. The garbage collector has more to do then, but better more garbage collection than memory leaks^^

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle Preview for Particular Keys means handle it inside onPress Method.

```
override fun onPress(primaryCode: Int) {
    handleKeyPreviews(primaryCode)
}

private fun handleKeyPreviews(code: Int) {
    when (code) {
        Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE, Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT, Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE, 32 ->
            keyboardView?.isPreviewEnabled = false
        else ->
            keyboardView?.isPreviewEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Graeme, Could you please help me to sort out this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53959115/in-android-custom-keyboard-how-to-change-alphabets-keyboard-to-symbols-keyboard