# Creating custom popup keyboard for alternative keys

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, gboard

I'm trying to create a custom popup keyboard for alternative keys in android. By using the default keyboard only customization I can do is to provide a custom layout for pop keyboard.

I need customize the behaviour as well (Like the one in the **Gboard**)  Such as,

(1) when a button is long pressed, by default it should highlight an specific key

(2) Keys can be highlighted and also selected by moving the finger(long press the key and move the finger same time)

These are the links I referenced:

[Building a custom android keyboard](http://www.blackcj.com/blog/2016/03/30/building-a-custom-android-keyboard/)

[Creating a SoftKeyboard with Multiple/Alternate characters per key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752580/creating-a-softkeyboard-with-multiple-alternate-characters-per-key)

[How do you disable the SoftKeyboard key preview window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770099/how-do-you-disable-the-softkeyboard-key-preview-window)

This is the popup keyboard in Gboard
[image]

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: @MateenChaudhry no

Comment: did you implemented suggestion in keyboard?

Comment: no actually. couldn't find a better solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you've already checked this article:
https://www.blackcj.com/blog/2016/03/30/building-a-custom-android-keyboard

It explains how to add a custom layout for the popup keyboard.
The only customization it allows is changing keys background and text color.

Also, you could use a `KeyboardView` subclass and then override its methods to achieve you goals, like `onTouchEvent()` to capture motion events or `onDraw()` to repaint keyboard regions:

```
<org.home.CustomPopupKeyboard
  android:id="@android:id/keyboardView"
  ...
/>
```

Also, check the **Hacker's Keyboard** source:
https://github.com/klausw/hackerskeyboard

Seems, it uses the `LatinKeyboardBaseView extends View` class for the popup keyboard, in the `layout/keyboard_popup.xml`.

---

**EDIT:**

According to the **Hacker's Keyboard** code, the only way I found to close the popup when a key is released is creating your own `KeyboardView` class, which extends the `View` directly, and then changing its `onTouchEvent()`.

The Android's native `KeyboardView` class has `PopupWindow mPopupKeyboard` property which is `private` so you can't subclass it and call `mPopupKeyboard.dismiss()` to hide the popup.

The chain that goes from releasing a key to the popup closing is:

- `LatinKeyboardBaseView::onTouchEvent()` > `case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: onUpEvent()` > `tracker.onUpEvent()`
- `PointerTracker::onUpEvent()` > `detectAndSendKey()` > `listener.onCancel()`
- `LatinKeyboardBaseView::onCancel()` (implementation of the `OnKeyboardActionListener` interface) > `dismissPopupKeyboard()` > `mMiniKeyboardPopup.dismiss()`

Answer (score -2):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:keyWidth="10%p"
        android:horizontalGap="0px"
        android:verticalGap="0px"
        android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height">
        <Row android:keyHeight="2px"></Row>
        <Row>
            <Key
                android:codes="49"
                android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
                android:keyLabel="1" />
            <Key
                android:codes="50"
                android:keyLabel="2" />
            <Key
                android:codes="51"
                android:keyLabel="3" />
            <Key
                android:codes="52"
                android:keyLabel="4" />
            <Key
                android:codes="53"
                android:keyLabel="5" />
            <Key
                android:codes="54"
                android:keyLabel="6" />
            <Key
                android:codes="55"
                android:keyLabel="7" />
            <Key
                android:codes="56"
                android:keyLabel="8" />
            <Key
                android:codes="57"
                android:keyLabel="9" />
            <Key
                android:codes="48"
                android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
                android:keyLabel="0" />
        </Row>

        <Row>
            <Key
                android:codes="113"
                android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
                android:keyLabel="q" />
            <Key
                android:codes="119"
                android:keyLabel="w" />

            <Key
                android:codes="101"
                android:keyLabel="e" />
            <Key
                android:codes="114"
                android:keyLabel="r" />
            <Key
                android:codes="116"
                android:keyLabel="t" />
            <Key
                android:codes="121"
                android:keyLabel="y" />
            <Key
                android:codes="117"
                android:keyLabel="u" />
            <Key
                android:codes="105"
                android:keyLabel="i" />

            <Key
                android:codes="111"
                android:keyLabel="o" />
            <Key
                android:codes="112"
                android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
                android:keyLabel="p" />
        </Row>


        <Row>

            <Key
                android:codes="97" android:keyLabel="a" android:horizontalGap="5%p"
                android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keyboard_popup_template"
                android:popupCharacters="áăä"/>
            <Key
                android:codes="115"
                android:keyLabel="s" />
            <Key
                android:codes="100"
                android:keyLabel="d" />
            <Key
                android:codes="102"
                android:keyLabel="f" />
            <Key
                android:codes="103"
                android:keyLabel="g" />
            <Key
                android:codes="104"
                android:keyLabel="h" />
            <Key
                android:codes="106"
                android:keyLabel="j" />
            <Key
                android:codes="107"
                android:keyLabel="k" />
            <Key
                android:codes="108"
                android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
                android:keyLabel="l" />


        </Row>

        <Row>
            <Key
                android:codes="-1" android:keyIcon="@drawable/narrow2"
                android:keyWidth="15%p" android:isModifier="true"
                android:isSticky="true" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
            <Key
                android:codes="122"
                android:keyLabel="z"
                android:keyWidth="15%p" />
            <Key
                android:codes="120"
                android:keyLabel="x"
                android:keyWidth="15%p" />
            <Key
                android:codes="99"
                android:keyLabel="c"
                android:keyWidth="15%p" />
            <Key
                android:codes="118"
                android:keyLabel="v"
                android:keyWidth="15%p" />
            <Key
                android:codes="98"
                android:keyLabel="b"
                android:keyWidth="15%p" />
            <Key
                android:codes="110"
                android:keyLabel="n"
                android:keyWidth="15%p" />
            <Key
                android:codes="109"
                android:keyLabel="m"
                android:keyWidth="15%p" />
            <Key
                android:codes="-5"
                android:isRepeatable="true"
                android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
                android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete"
                android:keyWidth="20%p" />
        </Row>

        <Row
            android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom"
            android:verticalGap="5px">

            <Key
                android:codes="-2"
                android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
                android:keyLabel="123"
                android:keyWidth="15%p" />
            <Key
                android:codes="64"
                android:keyLabel="\@"
                android:keyWidth="10%p" />

            <Key
                android:codes="-101"
                android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_language_switch"
                android:keyWidth="10%p" />
            <Key
                android:codes="32"
                android:isRepeatable="true"
                android:keyLabel="SPACE"
                android:keyWidth="30%p" />

            <Key
                android:codes="46"
                android:keyLabel="."
                android:keyWidth="10%p" />
            <Key
                android:codes="44"
                android:keyLabel=","
                android:keyWidth="10%p"
                android:popupCharacters=".,?!#@"
                android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keyboard_popup_template" />
            <Key
                android:codes="-4"
                android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
                android:keyLabel="DONE"
                android:keyWidth="20%p" />
        </Row>

        <Row android:keyHeight="2px"></Row>

    </Keyboard>

Please try it.
```

Comment: this is not answer to the question he is asking about custom popups