# In Android Custom Keyboard, how to change Alphabets Keyboard to Symbols Keyboard?

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard-events, android-input-method, android-custom-keyboard

While Navigate User from Alphabets Keyboard to Symbols Keyboard, Layout Alignment gets spoiled. By Default, Layout takes 5dp padding & User can't see the Last Column Keys.

Note: Images shown in below.

I handled Key Actions to Navigate User from Alphabets Keyboard to Symbol Keyboard in the onKey Method

```
override fun onKey(primaryCode: Int, keyCodes: IntArray?) {
when (primaryCode) {
        KEYCODE_ALPHABETS -> {
            keyboardView?.keyboard = Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard)
        }

        KEYCODE_SYMBOLS_1 -> {
            keyboardView?.keyboard = Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard_symbols_1)
        }

        KEYCODE_SYMBOLS_2 -> {
            keyboardView?.keyboard = Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard_symbols_2)
        }
 }
```

}

***Pls Suggest is there any other way to change keyboard (or) what I've done wrong***

What I faced is shown below.
Alphabets Keyboard:
[image]

While Change Keyboard in KeyboardView using setMethod in Kotlin, It changes with some mild UI Error

Symbols Keyboard:
[image]

**Note:**

- Symbols Keyboard has no issue. Bcz We tried to have it as a Primary
  Keyboard to inflate at very first time. It has no issue at that time.
- Issue is in Keyboard Change portion (onKey Method). Alphabets Keyboard also not fully compatible while changing Keyboard

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Jayce Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53959115/in-android-custom-keyboard-how-to-change-alphabets-keyboard-to-symbols-keyboard/59934561#59934561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboard Layout draws every key based on the **percentage** not in **dp**.
So declare your key width as **%p** not in **dp**

*In Layout file*

```
<Row
            android:horizontalGap="@fraction/key_horizontal_ten_keys_gap"
            android:keyWidth="@fraction/ten_keys_key_width"
            android:rowEdgeFlags="top">
</Row>
```

*In Resource file*

```
<fraction name="ten_keys_key_width">8.8%p</fraction>
```

Comment: Can you provide the list of keycodes for symbols for the keyboard

Comment: @Aan https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_0