# Android EditText alternative

Tags: android, performance, android-edittext, textview

Currently, Android's EditText is extremely slow when dealing with a huge amount of lines of text (10000+). It appears like this slowdown is partially due to the fact that EditText supports spans, and primarily due to the fact that EditText is calculating the width of each line, which is very expensive. Are there any faster alternatives to EditText, or a way to optimize it to make it usable?

EDIT: Method traces are as follows:

```
android.text.StaticLayout.generate: 99.1% CPU time inclusive, 8.8% exclusive (1 call)
    android.text.Layout.getParagraphSpans: 28% inclusive, 1.1% exclusive (4686 calls)
    android.text.MeasuredText.setPara: 20.6% inclusive, 1.6% exclusive (2343 calls)
    android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun: 18.6% inclusive, 1.1& exclusive (2343 calls)
    android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getSpans: 15% inclusive (of parent calls), 56.7% inclusive (of all calls, 47.3% of which are from android.text.Layout.getParagraphSpans, 26% are from android.text.MeasuredText.setPara, 26% are from android.text.StaticLayout.generate)
```

Comment: This is a problem I am exploring as well. My post gives a few solutions (although none are adequate) I proposed and tested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801232/edittext-performance-understanding-gpu-process-time-on-profile-gpu-rendering

Comment: Maybe you could set `singleLine="true"` so it doesn't have to render line widths? It also won't render anything past the margin until you scroll, at least it *shouldn't*.

Comment: @AaronGillion that does improve performance (albeit still not to a usable level), however it doesn't allowing for multi-line editing, which is something I need.

Comment: Try  android:hardwareAccelerated="false". It is out of EditText capability may be.

Comment: android:hardwareAccelerated="false" is helping a lot - performance is still not where it should be but it went from completely unusable to very sluggish  (but functional).

Comment: Does anyone have any idea why it is that setting hardwareAccelerated to false gives such a drastic improvement?

Comment: FWIW, I updated my post with a sample app for people to test themselves, and a couple of video demonstrations. Current consensus appears to be that the issue is related to certain GPUs. [My Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801232/edittext-performance-understanding-gpu-process-time-on-profile-gpu-rendering?noredirect=1#comment48024347_29801232) and [Sample App/Code](https://github.com/PPartisan/ASyncEditText)

Comment: Did you find any sollution for optimizing Edittext besides hardwareAccererate? I am struggling with the same problem right now.

Comment: EditText wasn't designed for this use case.  It was designed for entering a few lines of text.  You'll need to create a custom view for this.  That really shouldn't surprise you, do you think that a word processor uses the built in text tool in Windows?  If you have an extreme usecase, you need to do more work yourself.

Comment: @GabeSechanwell well, notepad manages somehow. Granted, that did severely limit the supported filesize for quite some time ...

Answer (score 6):

The best thing you can do is using `RecyclerView` with `EditText` as its item, so you get a new `EditText` for each of your lines.

New line will be the only thing you will have to implement.

Comment: Was this tested by anyone? How well did it do with performance and user interaction compared with EditText? It is hard to implement?

Comment: What ever you do, it will be hard to implement... But the performance rocks!

Comment: Do you know any newer alternative not suggested here? I saw apps like QuickEdit who have a editor with incredible performance even past 30k lines and they are clearly not using a recyclerview

Comment: I used a similar approach to scroll the entire [bible](https://www.amazon.com/Gazman-My-Bible/dp/B00E7OHKI0)

Comment: Isn't that a textview, or is your bible editable? But do you have an idea on how these apps do it?

Answer (score 2):

Although [this article](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/114508858967/improving-comment-rendering-on-android) only talks about optimizing static TextViews where the text doesn't change, it might get you on the right track for making a more performant EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using EditText inside a RelativeLayout, use LinearLayout instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't like this helps at all. In this vein - I've tried setting fixed widths and heights, and still no noticeable difference appears.

Comment: Can you check DDMS if it has a lot of redraws and recalculations occurrence

Comment: Also can you confirm the running OS version for the testing

Comment: I'm running Android 5.0, and it doesn't seem to matter which hardware (tried on multiple). I will update my OP with method tracing in a bit.

Comment: Before recommending to delete please consider http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer

Comment: This is also a good answer. On many devices using LinearLayout + fixed width does speed up EditText, esp. if the text is superlong. I've just tested on Samsung Tab S (Android 6).

Answer (score 0):

The alternative would be to use a `TextView` (how else would you show the text) and make it act as a `EditText`. Here's how:

You'll set an `OnClickListener` on your TextView, to show the keyboard:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        isEnteringText = true; //global
    }
});
```

And override `onKeyDown` and process keyboard presses to the TextView:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(isEnteringText) {
        textView.append(event.getDisplayLabel());
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Obviously this will need a lot of work, such as hiding the keyboard afterward, processing backspace & enter, and clipboard. I kinda formed my answer around [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14217535/android-softkeyboard-onkeydown-up-not-detecting-alternative-keys), you can try the other methods mentioned in there if you're having problems retrieving the keyboard keys. According to them, the above code will work as long as the language is English.

Comment: EditText is _"a thin veneer over TextView"_. The real problem is with the TextView even though the question is about EditText.