# how to make this highlight graphics when a key of Android keyboard (AOSP) is pressed

Tags: android

I am currently working on my own implementation of Input Method Editor (IME) or can be called as Soft keyboard in Android, I have read creating an input method and I have downloaded the Soft Keyboard sample code provided as part of the SDK, now I want to know how to make this 
highlight as showing in below image ,when I press any key of the keyboard. any one can tell me how to do that??

[image]

Comment: I'm newbie I do not have any idea, so please can you suggest me in that `Sample Code ` where can I find that and make some changes.

Comment: Here is a topic that explains what you want to do : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752580/creating-a-softkeyboard-with-multiple-alternate-characters-per-key

Comment: @kmas I have tried that but am not able to get the job done please can you code for only one key so that I can get hint and make my way clear.. plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to answer the question and I have made a significant effort, but this is not the perfect answer,  I have came up with following

**Step-1** create `custom_preview.xml` file in `drawable` folder write some thing like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:padding="5dp"
       android:shape="rectangle" >
      <solid android:color="#436EEE" />
      <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

**Step-2** create `popup_prewview_layout.xml` file in `layout` folder write this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
          android:layout_width="20dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/custom_preview"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:textSize="32sp" />
```

**Step-3** now in `main_layout.xml` add `android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/popup_preview_layout"`, like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.keyboard.KeyboardView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/keyboard"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:background="#FF272727"
          android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/keyboard_popup_preview"/>
```

**RESULT**
[image: RESULT]

OK so that was effort, but not the perfect solution for you, because there is not any `triangle` at the bottom of preview. that maybe an other question. Hope this is some thing working for you...

Comment: first of all `Thanks` for this guide, but how can I make that triangle  shape at the bottom of that preview as well please...