# How to disable key preview in popup keyboard (not in main softkeyboard layout)?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard, keypreview

It's easy to disable key previews: just call setPreviewEnabled(false) and these annoying tiny previews won't show up anymore. But if I attach a popup keyboard to any key then these previews will show up inside that popup:

qwerty.xml:

```
<Key android:codes="101" 
    android:keyLabel="E" 
    android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup"
   android:keyTextSize="60sp"/>
```

popup.xml:

```
<Row>
    <Key android:codes="-10000"
        android:keyLabel="test"
        android:keyOutputText="test"/>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key android:codes="-10001"
        android:keyLabel="test2"
        android:keyOutputText="test2"/>
</Row>
```

Can't post images, but if I long press letter 'E' and then press test or test2 button they will show that white key preview.

Is there any way to disable these key previews too?

Comment: Screenshots or mock picture will help understand the issue better.

Comment: @AndroidMechanic Here you go: http://pasteboard.co/1gjEd5Ye.jpg There is this white square appearing when I long-press on the popup keyboard..

Comment: Can you post your keyboardView please?

Answer (score 4):

set this in your popup layout set this attribute:

```
android:keyPreviewLayout="0"
```

or

```
android:keyPreviewLayout="@null"
```

Answer (score 3):

Call `setPreviewEnabled(false)` for the popup keyboard view too

```
// Find popup keyboard by its view-id
pKeyboardView
android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView = (KeyboardView)mHostActivity.findViewById(viewid);

// Disable key-previews for the popup keyboard too
pKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Where do I write that?

Answer (score 3):

create a CustomKeyboard with setPreviewEnabled(false) 
add your rows inside CustomeKeyboard in popup.xml as below

```
<CustomKeyboard 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:keyWidth="10%p"
        android:horizontalGap="0px"
        android:verticalGap="0px"
        android:keyHeight="60px" >
        <Row><Key android:codes="-10000"
            android:keyLabel="test"
            android:keyOutputText="test"/> </Row> 
        <Row><Key android:codes="-10001"
            android:keyLabel="test2"
            android:keyOutputText="test2"/></Row>
</CustomKeyboard>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your keyboardView set a layout for your popup with

```
android:popupLayout=""
```

And in your popup layout set this attribute:

```
android:keyPreviewLayout="@null"
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Your need to set your popupLayout your current popup layout is [this](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/keyboard_popup_keyboard.xml)

2) inside your popupLayout set android:keyPreviewLayout="@null" this will hide your preview inside popup

for more description [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752580/creating-a-softkeyboard-with-multiple-alternate-characters-per-key)