# Catch a Long press android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, virtual, long-press

I want to get a Long press key in a virtual android keyboard. I saw this code

```
@Override
public boolean onLongPress(Keyboard.Key key) {
    System.out.print("Get in long press");
    if (key.codes[0] == '1') {
        getOnKeyboardActionListener().onKey('!', null);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18932867/5458138)
. However, the `getOnKeyboardActionListener` on the KeyboardView has access protected.

Alone says cannot resolve method, but 
`mInputView.getOnKeyboardActionListener().onKey('!', null);` says access protected.

I add a print line, but if I remove all lines, leave only the print and do a long press on emulator, dont show the message on android Studio.

How can I solve this problem with this code or implement with another code?