# GridLayout for implementing a keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard, android-gridlayout, android-custom-keyboard

I need to implement a (soft)keyboard for an Android application.
Is GridLayout the correct View widget to contain all the keys?
Or is there other widget more suited for this specific requirement?

Comment: Have a look at this project: https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon it's kind of what you want IMHO

Comment: @Gavriel Thanks, I had a look. It uses GridView, which I think is meant for scrolling content out of screen, in my case all keys are visible all the time, so no need for an adapter View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a KeyboardView, it's very easy, you don't need to make all the keys or use specific layouts.

here a tutorial: http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm

And here you will see a implementation that I made:
[Soft keyboard's POPUP layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799775/android-soft-keyboards-popup-layout)

Comment: Thank you, exactly the info I was looking for. I was totally unaware of the KeyboardView.